# This is question is originally in context to elasticity (young mod, bulk mod etc). but i want some clarity on the tension forces (or torque)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, statics

I want to know what tension will there be in 2 strings if the are connected by rod and a mass is hung somewhere in between .I somewhat know the concept of torque but I am getting confused here . pls refer the image below ..
thanks for helping
EDIT: as someone pointed out that I haven't written the length from either side you shall assume it to be l1,l2.. (I just need to know the concept anyway.)
thanks again

[image: kindly refer this]

Comment: where is the mass hung? You haven't specified its distance from either end

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH i just need to know the concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, express the total torque on the rod around some point if your choosing; it should be zero. Then express the total vertical force on the rod; it should be zero too.

Say you pick the point where $m$ is attached as reference. $T_1$ adds a torque about this point in one direction. $T_2$ adds a torque in the opposite direction. They need to cancel each other out since it's a static situation. Then there are the linear forces - two up and one down. They also need to cancel out. Now you have two equations and two unknowns - solve away.

Comment: Thanks @Kristoffer could u please elaborate a little more.

Comment: Well, say you pick the point where $m$ is attached as reference.$T_1$ adds a torque about this point in one direction. $T_2$ adds a torque in the opposite direction. They need to cancel each other out since it's a static situation. Then there are the linear forces - two up and one down. They also need to cancel out. Now you have two equations and two unknowns - solve away.

Comment: ok got it thanks

Comment: you shall add/edit in the answer and i'll confirm/accept it